# Blackberry FB share prob: low memory

Tags: facebook, memory-management, blackberry, share

I am using Blackberry Facebook SDK (FacebookBlackBerrySDK-v0.8.25.jar) for facebook integration for my app. I am using the following code.

```
ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
          Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);

          try{

             FBUserDetails fbUserDetails = FBUserDetails.getInstance();

             String prevUserDatails = fbUserDetails.getFBData();           

             User user = fb.getCurrentUser();

             if(prevUserDatails != null && !prevUserDatails.equals("") && user.getEmail().equals(prevUserDatails)){

                if(Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO,"Do you want to post using FB account " + prevUserDatails + "?",Dialog.YES)==Dialog.NO){
                    fb.logout(true);
                    user = fb.getCurrentUser();
                }    
             }


             if(user!= null){

                fbUserDetails.persist(user.getEmail());

                String result = user.publishStatus(decodedText);
                if ((result != null) && !result.trim().equals("")) {
                    Dialog.alert("Successfully posted to Facebook.");                   
                } else {
                    Dialog.alert("Share Failed.");
                }

             }else
                Dialog.alert("user is equal to null.");

          }catch(FacebookException fe){
              fe.printStackTrace();
          }
```

When I am testing the app in Blackberry Strom 9300 (OS version 6.0.0.526), it is running properly first time. But when I am going to share the same text again in a short interval(it is obvious that the posting will fail),  system is giving "the memmory available on your device is low. Close some of the items below." and I forced to close the application. Can anyone tell me what is the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with my Webworks Blackberry build. The first time I begin using the app it is running fine but when I begin to process other pages on the app I receive a pop-up telling me that "the device memory is too low - please close the following items". Then the app icon changes to what looks like a folder.

I did some research and it appears this is a persistent problem on the Blackberry OS 6. Deleting the app and reinstalling it does not help neither does restarting the app.

Take a look at this link to view deeper issues related to low device memory

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Device-memory-is-Low-issue-for-an-WebWork-app/td-p/1166441/page/16